# Plot with two different x axis for the same variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to create a plot that displays a line with two x axis, one is a continuous numeric and the other is discrete.

This an example of the data:

```
df <-cbind.data.frame("Category"=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"), 
                   "Y"=c(5,6,4,8,9,4,5,3,7,8),
                   "X1"=c(0,10,20,30,40,0,10,20,30,40),
                   "X2"=c(0,0,1,1,2,0,1,2,2,3))
```

I tried to add a secondary axis and re-scale it, but since my two variables are not proportional I don't know how to re-scale so the same Y point in the line will fit both x axis.

```
ggplot(data=df) + 
 geom_path(aes(y=Y,x=X1),color="red")+ 
 geom_path(aes(y=Y,x=X2*10),color="blue")+ 
 facet_wrap(~Category)+ 
 scale_y_continuous("Y")+   
 scale_x_continuous("X1",sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .*1/10, "X2"))
```

I read different problems with two axis, but was not able to find a solution for my problem.

I am looking for something like this:

[image: Expected output]

I will appreciate a lot any help on this!

Comment: Could you share what output plot you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot you provide does not evidence a clear algebraic relationship, so I'm going to give you an example of a completely-arbitrary second x-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~., breaks=c(15,20,30), labels=c('a','b','c')))
```

[image: sample ggplot2 axis]

The first argument is the transformation "`~.`" (essentially `x2=x1`) and is required, so in this case it's a 1-for-1 transformation. The other two are relatively clear, you place `'a'` at `x=15`, `'b'` at `x=20`, etc. I don't think there's a way to put both on the same axis (with `ggplot2` alone).

Comment: This workaround sounds nice, but I guess that then I can't use the facet_wrap (since the second x scale will be different for each category)

Comment: `... + facet_wrap(~cyl)` worked for me, putting the second axis on each facet.

Comment: I don't think I understand how to do that, but I think I can work with the workaround using grid or something :D

Comment: I guess I don't understand ... I see your code for it, but there's no facet to it.

Comment: I mean I don't know how to add different secondary axis using facet_wrap (~Category), but I managed to use your code and arranging the plots with grid. Thanks a lot!! :D