# Tricky Figure: Plot values of two variable on same x-axis in R or excel

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2, plot, profile

I am trying to make a figure using this excel [Data here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X-UwYWmJ52HGqoU34usiqYCSnRSdcWdZ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113262485643338921756&rtpof=true&sd=true)like this [image: plot here], but I am unable to put two variables on x-axis with different values.

```
library(xlsx2)
test <- read.xlsx2("E:/Plot/oz.xlsx",1, header=TRUE) 
test$Ozone = as.numeric(as.character(test$Ozone))
test$Altitude = as.numeric(as.character(test$Altitude))
test$Pressure = as.numeric(as.character(test$Pressure))
round(test$Altitude) # i want to round the values of Altitude
library(ggplot2)
ylim.prim <- c(0, 34)   # in this example, precipitation
ylim.sec <- c(1010, 10) 
b <- diff(ylim.prim)/diff(ylim.sec)
a <- ylim.prim[1] - b*ylim.sec[1]
ggplot(test, aes(x = Ozone, y = Altitude,color = 'Ozone Partial Pressure (mPa)'))+ 
  geom_path(aes(x = Ozone))+ scale_y_continuous(name="Altitude (km)",sec.axis=sec_axis(~(.- a)/b, name = 'Pressure (hPa)'))+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Temperature (km)",sec.axis=sec_axis(~(.), name = 'Temperature (C)'))+
  theme_test() + theme(legend.position = c(0.01, 0.14),legend.justification = c(0, -4))
```

but I get a plot like this . [image: figure]

I would appreciate any help at this stage. Thank you

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68722954/profile-plot-using-ggplot2-two-variable-value-on-same-axis but doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: Same user with two accounts. I am desperate to find answers :) its urgent

Comment: Is this just about labels on the x-axis or do you want to draw a second line on this plot? If the latter, what should the x,y variables of the second line be?

Comment: just the value with axis name: plz have a look at the example graph ...x-axis should have temperature and ozone ... y aixs will remain the same

Comment: This question was raised 2 yrs back but with no answers 
 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833159/plot-with-two-different-x-axis-for-the-same-variable-in-r

Comment: What transformation would you like between your first and second x-axis?

Comment: Sorry I ddnt get you. The figure I made has one line for ozone but I need to put temperature line along with partial ozone. the values on x-axis should have two axis values as one for partial ozone and another for temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two labels per break, you can seperate them with `\n`. You can do this manually, or if you know the transformation with a function provided to the `labels` argument of the scale.  From the example figure I glanced that temperature is `4x - 100` wherein `x` is the ozon label. However, temperature and ozone don't appear to be colinear from your data.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Downloaded from google sheets as tsv
file <- file.choose()
df <- read.table(file, sep = "\t", header = TRUE)

# Per example figure
ozone2temp <- function(x){x * 4 - 100}

# Simplified for brevity
ggplot(df) +
  geom_path(aes(Ozone, Altitude, colour = "Ozone")) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = function(x) {
      paste(x, ozone2temp(x), sep = "\n")
    },
    name = "Ozone\nTemp"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### EDIT:

If you want to also plot altitude with temperature as the x-variable, you need the reverse transformation as well:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Downloaded from google sheets as tsv
file <- file.choose()
df <- read.table(file, sep = "\t", header = TRUE)

# Per example figure
ozone2temp <- function(x){x * 4 - 100}
temp2ozone <- function(x){(x + 100) / 4}

ggplot(df, aes(y = Altitude)) +
  geom_path(aes(Ozone, colour = "Ozone")) +
  geom_path(aes(temp2ozone(Temperature), 
                colour = "Temperature")) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = function(x) {
      paste(x, ozone2temp(x), sep = "\n")
    },
    name = "Ozone\nTemp"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thats great ! Thank you very much. for adding temperature to it do I have to call again "geom_path(aes(x=Temperature),color="blue")"   in addition to "geom_path(aes(x=Ozone),color="red")

Comment: Got it this time. Many thanks to you for your support. Tomorrow is last date for review and hopefully this figure ll be published. I'll revert back to this post and let you know. :)

Comment: Hey ... @teunbrand I came back to say thank for your help and acknowledged in my research work which is published today. Thank you. https://authors.elsevier.com/c/1e2jLB8ccr2Bu    DOI here: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.scitotenv.2021.151135

Comment: That's great, congratulations with the publication :) I'm not sure I merit a formal acknowledgement for this tiny piece of code, but thanks!